# Using Entity for SecurityUserProvider on Silex

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, silex

On silex, my authentication works when I use a simple UserProvider with Doctrine ORM (just DBAL) :

```
$app['security.firewalls']=array(
 'app_secure' => array(
    'pattern' => '^/app/',
    'form' => array(
        'login_path' => '/login',
        'check_path' => '/app/login_check',
        'always_use_default_target_path' => true,
        'default_target_path' => '/app/'
        ),

    'logout' => array(
        'logout_path' => '/app/logout',
        'target_url' => "/login",
        'invalidate_session'=> "true"
        ),

    'users' => $app->share(function() use ($app) {
        return new App\Service\UserProvider($app['db']);
    })
  ),
);
```

On the Silex documentation, I have read :

> If you are using the Doctrine ORM, the Symfony bridge for Doctrine provides a user provider class that is able to load users from your entities.

So I try to work with Entities (with the dflydev Doctrine ORM Service Provider) but I can't find how to configure my firewall :

```
'users' => $app->share(function() use ($app) {
            $em = $app['orm.em'];
            return $em->getRepository('MyProject\Entity\User');
        })
```

This solution return me an error :  `attempts a UserProvider`.

> One of my sources : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/silex-php/k-0X-BdG6Zw

What I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As stated in the docs](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#defining-a-custom-user-provider):

> The users setting can be defined as a service that returns an instance
>   of UserProviderInterface

You have to make sure that the user repository is implementing the [UserProviderInterface](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserProviderInterface.html).

In order to use the Doctrine one (take this with caution, I've never used it!), you first need to install the DoctrineBridge (`composer require symfony/doctrine-bridge 2.7`) and then just configure the [Doctrine user provider](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Security/User/EntityUserProvider.php#L28):

```
<?php

$app['security.firewall'] = array(
  //...
  'users' => function() use ($app) {
    return new Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\EntityUserProvider($app['registry_manager'], 'MyProject\Entity\User');
  }
```

Be aware, you'll need a *ManagerRegistry* instance, you can take a look at this [registry manager provider](https://github.com/saxulum/saxulum-doctrine-orm-manager-registry-provider) or create one on your own.

Comment: your answer and this (in french) solved my problem :
http://prof.bpesquet.fr/tutoriel/developpement-php-moderne/#toc_51